# Range Slider oninput function doesn't execute when clicked and dragged

Tags: javascript, rangeslider

I have a simple range slider defined as follows:

```
    <input class="panning-control" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
```

In the Javascript tag I declare

```
var panControl = document.querySelector('.panning-control');
```

and then have the following oninput function:

```
panControl.oninput = function() {
  //a bunch of irrelevant computations involving panControl.value
}
```

The problem is that when I click and drag the slider quickly, the oninput function doesn't execute for each 'step'. for example if I clicked and dragged the slider from 0 to 50, the oninput function should theoretically execute 50 times, because step=1 and the slider went from 0 to 50. Right now, if you click and drag the slider it skips executing the function from most of the steps, and the calculations that I do in oninput done with the wrong numbers because each execution of the function depends on the computations done from the last execution. It does work if i just click on the slider once, and then use the left and right arrow keys to increment and decrement the slider. Does anyone have a solution for this? Is there another knob/control package that I can utilize?

Comment: What browser are you testing this in. IE doesn't provide the behavior you want.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS

Comment: Please try **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2pfm40a/)** and let me know what the results are.

Comment: I printed panControl.value using console.log() and it seems to be behaving the same.

Comment: Ok, then it's probably a Mac OS issue because it works as you want in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: okay, thanks for the help

Comment: just to clarify, when you run it on a windows machine and turn the knob from 0 to 50 with a console.log() statement, it prints a message 50 times in the console?

Comment: Yes, it does just that.

Comment: i just ran it on a windows machine and saw the following results: https://postimg.cc/image/nh6l85bsr/ maybe we're not on the same page, but I wanted to knob to print out 1, 2, 3, ... 47.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the addEventListener(event, handler, bubbles) method

```js
var panControl = document.querySelector('.panning-control');
panControl.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
    doSomething(evt.target.value);
}, false);

function doSomething(value) {
    var output = document.querySelector('.output');
    output.textContent = value;
}
```

```html
  <input class="panning-control" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" />
<span class="output"></span>
```

Comment: `.addEventListener()` is the modern approach, but it has no difference in when the event fires than `oninput`. Also, please don't post working code to 3rd party sites in answers as those links can die over time. Just insert your working code into a "code snippet", right here in your answer. Lastly, don't use `.innerHTML` when the string to be set/gotten doesn't contain any HTML. For those, use `.textContent`.

Comment: It still seems to be skipping iterations of the function. I added the following line to doSomething(): 
console.log(panControl.value);
and it seems to be skipping many executions of the function.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus, fixed the formatting and the innerHTML